# Load data dynamically on Scroll in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would load data on Scroll instead an ajax call, my code is:

```
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: { get_param: 'value' },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    var HTML ='<div>'
                        + ' <div><a href="/user/'+ element.username +'">' + element.name + '</a></div>';
```

```
                    $('#api').append(HTML);

                });
```

My problem is adding the scroll in append(), how i can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "my problem is adding the scroll"?  Is the browser somehow not letting you scroll down to view the new content, or something else?

Comment: What do you mean to append scroll? You mean you want to have scrolls at the #api element?

Comment: I need to load data onScroll like Infinite scroll, the data should load only when I scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Infinite scroll still relies on AJAX. It just makes the query incrementally rather than pulling the entire data set all at once.
2. To make this work, your API has to have the ability to pull the data incrementally using queries. If it dont, then you have to pull the entire dataset and build your parser on the front end.
3. Use a scroll handler to monitor window position. Set an offset position for where you want the query to happen (trigger it at 3/4 page height for best results)